Monitorix disable subgraphs
I have a Monitorix service running on my system. By changing y/n values in the graph_enable section I can enable and disable certain graphs, however, there are subgraphs for almost every main graph e.g.:
    _fs1            = Filesystems usage
    _fs2            = Disk I/O activity
    _fs3            = Inode usage
    _fs4            = Time spent in I/O activity

How can I hide _fs3 and _fs4 if I am only interested in _fs1 and _fs2?
These graphs in the config file are only present in the graphs section and seem to only set the titles for the subgraphs.
